# Is it possible to load Current Item list info into a WorkFlow custom form?

Tags: 2013, workflow, custom-form

Hoping a friendly and knowledgeable community member can assist or confirm:

I am attempting to build a custom workflow form in Sharepoint 2013 that will display specific List Item info related to the item that the workflow is regarding.   As I've built the workflow to be launched via an email link (Using a URL to the workflow and substituting the Current Item:ID), I am attempting to avoid confusion by individuals completing the workflow and ensuring that they know the particulars of the list item.

However, I have not been able to figure out a way to have the workflow form reference the current item that it is based on.  I have added a secondary data connection to the list itself and have queried that data connection on form load, along with setting field values from the data connection to the workflow form on form load, but I have only been able to retrieve the top item of the list, rather than the current item the workflow is based off of.

Any suggestions are welcome, or confirmation that what I am attempting to accomplish just is not possible.

Thank you!